# transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

Tags: java

Code Example Here : Eclipse & Tomcat 
I got bug in : transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

EveryOne know what is happen in it 
Share with me solve

Thank you !

```
protected SOAPMessage onMessageSOAP(SOAPMessage message, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws SOAPException {
        String prefixLog = "WSSOAP.onMessageSOAP: ";
        // Extract the content of the reply
        SOAPMessage reply = null;
        String servicePrefix = "tns";
        String serviceURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPBody body = null;
        try {
            String username = WSSOAP.EMPTY_STR;
            String password = getEmptyPassword();

            SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
            String inputNamespaceURI = WebserviceLauncher.findNameSpaceBody(message);
            boolean isUnified = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("isUnified"));

            try {
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Comment: Please add the exception stack trace.

Comment: I will try to add stack trace and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : In Eclipse IDE

Step1 : Click Project/ Propertie
Step2 : Click on Order and Export ( in Java Build Path ) 
Step3 : Select " JRE System library[java8] " 
Step4 : Up "On the Top "

Priority to run "Java8 Library" first ( Solve ) 
Bug is : Lot of libarry confilict